# I have a 'UIImage' and I want to convert it to NSData to upload on firebase storage

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to upload an Image of type Jpeg to firebase storage

Below is the function to upload to firebase storage

```
func uploadImageToFirebase (data: NSData){

         let StorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("User Products")
        let uploadMetadata = StorageMetadata()
        uploadMetadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        StorageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: uploadMetadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if (error != nil){

                print("I have an error")
            }else {
                print("upload metadata \(String(describing: metadata))")
            }

        }
```

Here I have the picker controller function which is located in another class called `CamViewController`

here I call the function from `Mainviewcontroller` class

```
var discover = MainViewController()
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
          imageCam.image = image

        discover.uploadImageToFirebase(data: image)

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type `UIImage?` to expected argument type `NSData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
func uploadImageToFirebase (_ image:UIImage){
  gurad let data = image.pngData() else { return }
  ..... OR
  guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }

}
```

---

```
discover.uploadImageToFirebase(image)
```

the error is clear the parameter type is `NSData` so you can't pass a `UIImage`